# Recursividade de pastas e arquivos armazenados no Banco de Dados - PHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2, recursão, sistema-de-arquivos

Eu tenho um sistema usando o CakePHP, em uma das páginas há a possibilidade de cadastrar pastas e arquivos recursivos, que ficam salvos no banco de dados. 
Agora, eu preciso consultar essas pastas e arquivos, logicamente com recursividade e reproduzir algo como isso:

[image: (Pasta filha de 'Arquivos enviados')]

[image: (Arquivo filho da pasta 'Gerais')]

Porém estou com dificuldade na hora de obter esses dados do banco de dados. As pastas recursivas estão sendo recuperadas corretamente através da classe 'Tree' do CakePHP, mas os arquivos que são salvos em outra tabela, não. Será que alguém pode me ajudar? (Caso necessário disponibilizo o código que estou usando). Obrigada!

Comment: Incluí a estrutura do seu banco na pergunta, isso vai ajudar.

Comment: o Tree só lista os diretórios e arquivos, para você localizar no banco de dados, você tem q fazer um select pelo nome do arquivo, ou não usar o Tree e listar tudo com um select nas tabelas do banco de dados.